# событие onClick

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

```js
  var bigsize = "300"; //Размер большой картинки
  var smallsize = "150"; //Размер маленькой картинки
  function changeSizeImage(im) {
    if (im.height == bigsize) im.height = smallsize;
    else im.height = bigsize;
  }
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <img src="https://myrusakov.ru/images/articles/Foto1.jpg" height="150" onclick="changeSizeImage(this)" />
      <br />
      <b>Фото 1</b>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <img src="https://myrusakov.ru/images/articles/Foto2.jpg" height="150" onclick="changeSizeImage(this)" />
      <br />
      <b>Фото 2</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Здесь все работает. Но я не могу понять как это работает? Ведь переменные `bigsize` and `smallsize` вне функции и как проходит логическая проверка `if (im.height == bigsize)`, если по клику нигде не подставляется `bigsize`? `bigsize` ведь сам по себе вне функции. В моем понимании это как так, если клик то присвоить bigsize. Объясните, пожалуйста, подробнее как этот код работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В javascript из функции видны глобальные переменные. Если вы обращаетесь к переменной в функции, js сначала будет искать их внутри функции и если не найдет будет искать в глобальной области видимости.

Comment: Ну это понятно, а как по клику меняется высота, ведь мы изначально не где не присваиваем значение переменной smallsize

Comment: тогда не понял,а эта строчка что делает  var smallsize = "150"; //Размер маленькой картинки ?

Comment: if (im.height == bigsize) im.height = smallsize;
    else im.height = bigsize;     код здеь выполнятся будет  начала же с логической проверки if верно? Так вот я спрашиваю как она может выполнить проверку если мы в начале не где не говорили что im == bigsize.

Comment: ну в функции смотрится если  высота переданной картинки в функцию ровна глобальной переменной bigsize то ее высоте присваивается значение  глобальной переменной smallsize иначе ее высоте присваивается значение глобальной переменной bigsize. Как я говорил если в функции не находиться переменная, она начинает искаться в глобальной области видимости. В чем именно вопрос то ?

Comment: У Вас есть skype?